# Finding the sum of the numbers seen so far using C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out a way to print out the cumulative sum of the numbers seen so far in an input using c++.

After the user inputs any sequence of numbers(0,2,7,8,3,9,2,9,1,8), The output should be (0,2,9,17,20,29...). So basically it adds the next number into the current sum. I tried the n(n-1)/2 but that only works for finding the total sum. I want to find the total sum at each integer.

This is what I have so far which only prints out the integer entered.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    signed short val;
    while ( cin >> val ) {
        cout << val << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me. I would greatly appreciate any type of feedback.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to output the cumulative sum as you input or only after inputting all the values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need somewhere to store the cumulative sum:

```
int cumulative_sum = 0;
```

You then need to add each value into the `cumulative_sum`:

```
cumulative_sum += val;
```

Then you need to print out the `cumulative_sum` each time. You can do that.

Comment: @bolov Way ahead of you! And by "way", I mean about half a second.

Comment: sometime half of second is all that matter :p

Comment: I like the final paragraph, for good answers like these I hope no other gets into just writing down the program...

Comment: Thanks Joseph. That works wonderfully. Please Excuse my ignorance. I started coding just yesterday. :)